# How can I display no results text in a template?

Tags: views, theming

I have added no results behaviour text to a view called Events which is a page. This template I am using has a twig called views-view--events--page_1.twig. I want to add the no results text to this twig template, but I can't find any way to do it. How can this be done?

Comment: Look for `views-view.html.twig` in core and compare it with your template. You may be missing a lot more than just the empty case. Also, twig overrides end in `.html.twig`. See [Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/10.0.x) for the correct way to name your views templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always useful to look at the original template ([views-view.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view.html.twig/8.2.x)). The documentation list the available variables, which in this case are the following.

> - attributes: Remaining HTML attributes for the element
> - css_name: A css-safe version of the view name
> - css_class: The user-specified classes names, if any
> - header: The optional header
> - footer: The optional footer
> - rows: The results of the view query, if any
> - empty: The content to display if there are no rows
> - pager: The optional pager next/prev links to display
> - exposed: Exposed widget form/info to display
> - feed_icons: Optional feed icons to display
> - more: An optional link to the next page of results
> - title: Title of the view, only used when displaying in the admin preview
> - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be displayed in front of the view title
> - title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be displayed after the view title
> - attachment_before: An optional attachment view to be displayed before the view content
> - attachment_after: An optional attachment view to be displayed after the view content
> - dom_id: Unique id for every view being printed to give unique class for Javascript

`{{ empty }}` appears to be what you're after.